# "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" when updating circles

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am trying to implement a "Rescale" feature in which when I press a button, the SVG canvas updates the axis and circles with the data for the rescaled axis.

However, I keep getting the aforementioned error above. The circles are removed without issues, and the axis does rescale. What could be the problem? My code is below.

```
            var button = d3.select("body")
                .append("input")
                .attr("type","button")
                .attr("value", "Rescale");

            var toggle;

            button.on("click", function(){
                toggle = !toggle;

                xScale_left = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain((toggle ? [0,7.5] : [6,7.5]))
                    .range([0, width / 2]);

                xScale_right = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain((toggle ? [0,7.5] : [6,7.5]))
                    .range([width / 2, width]);

                xAxis_left = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(xScale_left)
                    .tickValues((toggle ? [1,6,7] : [6.1,7.1,7.2,7.3,7.4]))
                    .orient("bottom");

                xAxis_right = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(xScale_right)
                    .tickValues((toggle ? [1,6,7] : [6.1,7.1,7.2,7.3,7.4]))
                    .orient("bottom");

                svg = d3.select("body").transition();

                svg.select(".xaxis-left") // change the x axis
                    .duration(1500).ease("sin-in-out")
                    .call(xAxis_left);

                svg.select(".xaxis-right") // change the x axis
                    .duration(1500).ease("sin-in-out")
                    .call(xAxis_right);

                svg.selectAll(".nodes").remove();

                circles = svg.selectAll(".nodes")
                    .data(data) // This is where the error occurs
                    .enter()
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("class", "nodes");

                circles
                    .append("circle")
                    .attr("cx", function(d) {
                        if (d.qResult === "Apples" || d.qResult === "Kiwis") {
                            return xScale_right(d.KCComment);
                        } else {
                            return xScale_left(d.KCComment);
                        }
                    })
                    .attr("cy", function(d) {
                        if (d.qResult === "Apples" || d.qResult === "Oranges") {
                            return yScale_top(d.pscoreResult);
                        } else {
                            return yScale_bottom(d.pscoreResult);
                        }
                    })
                    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
                    .attr("class", "circle")
                    .style("fill", function(d){
                        if(d.qResult == "Apples"){
                            return "#de2533";
                        } else if(d.qResult == "Oranges") {
                            return "#ef7600";
                        } else if(d.qResult == "Blueberries") {
                            return "#595194";
                        } else{
                            return "#46ad00";
                        }
                    });
            });
```

Comment: Does the message/debugger not give the location of the error?

Comment: @AlexK. it does, I have commented the location in my code.

It occurs here: 

    circles = svg.selectAll(".nodes")
                    .data(data)